# Global variable change to null after calling an action in controller

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to call delete action, but my global variable sets to null.
Controller:

```
App::uses('AppController', 'Controller');

class WhitelistController extends AppController
{
public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');

private $deletes;


public function index()
{
    if ($this->request->is('post'))
    {

        $whitelist = $_POST['data']['whitelist']['stylecodes'];
        if($whitelist == "")
            return $this->Session->setFlash('You did not enter stylecodes. If you send this, it will delete all the shoes from the website.');


        $whitelist = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $whitelist);
        $whitelist = explode(",", $whitelist);


        $url = 'http://fonda.vps.***********/product_import_json_all_published_products';
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $all = curl_exec($ch);
        $all = json_decode($all, true);
        print_r($all);

        $this->deletes = array_diff($all, $whitelist);

        if($this->deletes == $all)
            return $this->Session->setFlash('It seems you entered wrong data, what could delete all of the shoes from the website.');


        $this->deletes = array_values($this->deletes);
        pr($this->deletes);

        $this->set('delete', $this->deletes);
        $this->render('delete');
    }

}

public function delete()
{
    if($this->request->is('post'))
    {


    }else{

        $url = 'http://fonda.vps.*******/product_import_json_remove';
        $myvars = 'products=' . json_encode($this->deletes);
        print_r();

        pr($myvars);
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $myvars);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $response = json_decode($response, true);

        pr($response);





        $removed = count($response['removed']);
        $skipped = count($response['skipped']);

        $string = $removed . " shoe(s) removed and " . $skipped . " shoe(s) skipped.";
        $this->Session->setFlash($string);

        if (count($response['error']) != 0) {
            $string = "";
            echo " ";
            foreach ($response['error'] as $key => $value) {
                $string .= $key . ": " . $value;
                $string .= "\n";
            }
            $this->Session->setFlash('Error found in following shoe(s): ' . $string);
        }

        return $this->redirect(array( 'action' => 'index'));

    }
}


}
```

$this->deletes gets null after calling the delete() from the view.

I don't see anything that changes the deletes value.

What is the problem?

Comment: There are no global variables in the question, did you mean on this line `$myvars = 'products=' . json_encode($this->deletes);`? Note that you shouldn't be referering to `$_POST`, use `$this->data` and.. that code aught to be in a model class.

Comment: [That's a class property](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).

Comment: So I can't pass class properties from a function to another?

Comment: The problem you have at the moment is a (lack of |mis)understanding, and if far broader than the question asked. Http [is a stateless protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol). That means that the request you make to delete _is completely separate_ from any previous request you may have made. This has nothing to do with global variables, and nothing to do with passing variables from one function to another. When delete is executed, _the index function is not_ - it may as well not exist. I recommend some broader/background reading on php/web dev in general.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I removed the global variable, and i put the local variable to a session in the first action:

```
$this->Session->write('deletes', $delete);
```

And i read it in the second action like this:

```
$delete = $this->Session->read('deletes');
```

so i could work with the $delete in the second action.

Comment: It's a much better idea to delete the records explicitly requested, instead of the records which were last displayed in the browser. You can (I hope) easily imagine deleting something you didn't intend that way.